# How to include link in a mail body message?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, smtp, visual-studio-2013

I want to send an email with a hyperlink, I tried to send the email without the link and its worked, but when I add the link it gives an error

This is my code:

```
MailMessage o = new MailMessage("f@hotmail.com", "f@hotmail.com", "KAUH Account Activation", "Hello, " + name + "\n Your KAUH Account about to activate click the link below to complete the actination process \n "+<a href=\"http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx">login</a>);
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("f@hotmail.com", "****");
SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
smtpobj.Credentials = netCred;
smtpobj.Send(o);
```

Comment: That link-markup must be part of the body-string, it can't just "hang around"

Comment: If you look carefully at the formatting the StackOverflow engine did for you when you posted your code, an issue does kind of jump out at you.

Comment: @JMK I think that visual interpret this "+<a href=\" as a string so the rest of the real string does the error, I dont know how to deal with the link and the string in the same time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to enable HTML for the body of the `MailMessage` like so:

```
o.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Maybe you should choose another constructor, to make the code more readable. Something like this perhaps:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com", "Customer Service");
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@domain.com"));
mailMessage.Subject = "A descriptive subject";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.Body = "Body containing <strong>HTML</strong>";
```

Full docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(v=vs.110).aspx

**Update**
It seems like it is your string building that cause you trouble. Sometimes, when putting strings together (or concatenating them as it is called) it is tricky to get all quotes correct. When creating such a large string as an email, there are some options to get it right.

**First**, regular string - downside is that it's hard to read

```
string body = "Hello, " + name + "\n Your KAUH Account about to activate click the link below to complete the actination process \n <a href=\"http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx">login</a>";
```

**Second**, verbatim string - allows line breaks in the code which improved readability. Note the @ character in the beginning and that the quote escape sequence changed from `\"` to `""`.

```
string body = @"Hello, " + name + "\n Your KAUH Account about to
    activate click the link below to complete the actination process \n 
    <a href=""http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx"">login</a>"
```

**Third**, string builder. This is actually the preferred way in many regards.

```
var body = new StringBuilder();
body.AppendFormat("Hello, {0}\n", name);
body.AppendLine(@"Your KAUH Account about to activate click 
    the link below to complete the actination process");
body.AppendLine("<a href=\"http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx\">login</a>");
mailMessage.Body = body.ToString();
```

StringBuilder docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you Mikael, I think that visual interpret this "+<a href=\" as a string so the rest of the real string does the error,, I dont know how to deal with the link and the string in the same time

Comment: @F505 - that link is nothing special. At this moment the markup is just string content. Only at the mail client that html body is interpreted as "html" and then it becomes a link.

Answer (score 3):

mark message as html `o.IsBodyHtml = true`

Answer (score 3):

```
     String body = "ur message : <a href='http://www.yoursite.com'></a>"
     o.Body = body;

o.IsBodyHtml = true
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget to escape the " : href=\" .... \">login

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error:

```
MailMessage o [...snip...] \n "+<a href=\"http://localh [...snip...]
                              ^--terminates the string
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--interpreted as code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = lblHidOnlineURL.Value + hidEncryptedEmpCode.Value;
body = hid_EmailBody.Value.Replace("@Compting", "HHH").Replace("@toll", hid_TollFreeNo.Value).Replace("@llnk", "<a style='font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; color: #800000; font-weight: bold' href='http://" + url + "'>click here To Download</a>");
```